# How to get only status of Sutosys job like SU, RU etc

Tags: unix, autosys

I want only job status value like RU,SU,OH etc to collect that in a variable, i am trying below command

```
autorep -J jobname -d -L0
```

but it giving me whole result including all other column like Job Name,Last Start,Last End,ST/Ex,Run/Ntry Pri/Xit

I just want column ST value

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the output to awk command to get the "ST/Ex" column which is 4th field

```
autorep -J jobname -d -L0 | awk '{print $4}'
```

Good Luck!!